# Cell fracture not working on procedural texture

Tags: procedural, cell-fracture

I'm trying to make a cell fracture on a mesh with a procedural texture. It works fine if I try it on a mesh without a procedural texture or with a procedural texture with less nodes. But on this mesh it doesn't. I tried lowering the source limit in the cell fracture window from 1200 to 10. It does not help. Finally I give up and make a force quit.

My guess is that the procedural texture on the mesh is too complicated for my computer RAM to add a cell fracture to it. Could that be correct?

Best

Staffan [image: Cell fracture]

Comment: Have you tried to link the material after all the fragments are created? (Start with a dummy material, then link the real material). If you want to share your blend file we can give it a try and give you feedback. Just with the text and screenshot, it's hard to tell what's the problem and if it's your computer.

Comment: I tried linking the real material to the fractured dummy. For some reason the fractures didn´t get the real material. Is it really possible to add a blender file 145 MB big here?

Comment: No, you can't upload over 20MB here. Do you have a google drive or drive one, dropbox? Looks like you can upload file to Wetransfer.com for a week, too

Comment: Ok! Here it isL https://drive.google.com/file/d/18NBo_yBp2s-L4UW_-e3JLACMmxTbEQYd/view?usp=sharing

Comment: The sphere (*bumpy*) has 600k vertices + 200k for the particles (*red thing*). That's a lot. Have you tried to reduce the number of vertices? You can bake a normal map to add the texture details to the low-poly version. The shader might look a bit different for *bumpy* if you remesh and decimate the mesh.